# How can i merge 2 sheets into 1 in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 sheets in excel. Some of the rows are common and some of them are different. How can I combine them into 1 spread sheet?

Thank you.

Comment: From your statement "Some of the rows are common," I presume you're looking for something a bit more sophisticated than copy and paste.  If so, can you please describe in more detail what you mean by "merge"?  Snapshots of the current sheets and what you want the result to look like would be very helpful.  If your data are sensitive or overly complicated, create simple sample data that illustrate the essential complexity of the real data (but no more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all the cells in the second sheet, copy to clipboard, select a cell below or to the left of all your content on your first sheet, and paste.

Select the Cells on the second sheet:
 [image]

Copy, choose where to put it in the first sheet, [image]

and paste. All the formulas and links to cells should carry over.

[image]